# Get current project in a wizard (Eclipse RCP)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I found some ways to get the current project but if I'm in a wizard the workbench seems to be inaccessible at that moment, therefore this line always returns `null`:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
```

Besides that, that approach seems to work only when an editor is opened, can someone give me some pointers or share a simple method to get the current project?

I found several snippets of code but I simply can't get this work, and some of them only works when there's an opened editor.

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse does not really have a concept of a 'current' project. As the answer below shows you can get the currently selected object but it is possible there may not be anything currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

I your wizard implements IWorkbenchWizard interface, you will have a method with the following signature to implement:

```java
void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection)
```

The selection parameter will hold IResource objects that were selected in the current navigator when launching your wizard. From IResource, you can get the project.